# How to create a list favourite in windows phone

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xml-parsing

i want make a list of favourite videos in windows phone 8. I think a xml file will help me, now i want to creat xml file as

```
<Videos>
  <video>abc</video>
  <video>xyz</video>
  ........
<Videos/>
```

but i dont know how to do creat that xml file and the way to read it out . Can you help me, Thanks a lot !

Comment: Try posting the code of what you've tried doing so far. Otherwise, you question is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

Create XML document :

```
List<string> videos=new List<string>();
videos.Add("abc");
videos.Add("xyz");
//add as many items you want.
List<XElement> childElements=new List<XElement>();
videos.Foreach(el=>childElements.Add(new XElement("video",el.ToString())));
XDocument doc=new XDocument(new XElement("Videos",childElements));
doc.save("file.xml");
```

Reading it back to the list :

```
Xdocument doc=XDocument.Load("file.xml");
List<string> videos=(from el in doc.Root.Elememts("video") select el.Value).ToList();
```